# Wilcoxon test with chicken's weight

Tags: r

```
data(ChickWeight)
head(ChickWeight)
plot( ChickWeight$Time, ChickWeight$weight, col=ChickWeight$Diet)
chick = reshape(ChickWeight, idvar=c("Chick","Diet"), timevar="Time",
                direction="wide")
head(chick)
chick = na.omit(chick)
```

> Perform a t-test of x and y, after adding a single chick of weight 200
> grams to x (the diet 1 chicks). What is the p-value from this test?
> The p-value of a test is available with the following code:
> t.test(x,y)$p.value

Do the same for the Wilcoxon test. The Wilcoxon test is robust to the outlier. In addition, it has less assumptions that the t-test on the distribution of the underlying data.

When I try do Wilcoxon test:

```
wilcox.test(c(x, 200), y)
```

I get this error:

```
Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(c(x, 200), y) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Comment: What is `x` and `y` in your example

Comment: First it is a warning and not an Error. The Wilcoxon test is ranks there values of  x and y.  If there is tie where x(i)=y(i) the final ranking is different if x is listed before y or vice versa, thus generating the error. If the number of ties is small compare to the  whole sample then the error will generally cancel out and the warning can be disregarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exactRankTests::wilcox.exact`:

If `x` is a weight for example time 0 e.g. `chick$weight.0` and
`y` is a weight for example time 2 e.g. `chick$weight.2`

Then you could do it this way:

With `wilcox.test` you will get a warning message:

```
> wilcox.test(c(chick$weight.0, 200), chick$weight.2)$p.value
[1] 6.660003e-14
Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(c(chick$weight.0, 200), chick$weight.2) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Use `exactRankTests::wilcox.exact()` that can handle ties:

```
t.test(chick$weight.0,chick$weight.2)$p.value
6.660003e-14

exactRankTests::wilcox.exact(c(chick$weight.0, 200), chick$weight.2)$p.value
[1] 5.889809e-18
```